# Rails setting selection tag to predifined value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a add function + view. In some cases a user can specify to do some action and call a function that should submit a id to the add function. (that works)

Now I wanted that if this param is not nil then a selection tag should be predifined with this value.

I tried this:

```
<% if !params[:channel_id].nil? %>
      <% :channel_id << params[:channel_id] %>
<% end %>
```

Thats not working.

selection tag looks like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :channel_id, @channels, :id, :channelname, {prompt: (t "channel.add.prompt")}, class: "form-control", :required => :true %>
```

is there a solution to achieve this?

Comment: Please post how your `form_for` definition looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just add the value to your `collection_select`:

```
<%= f.collection_select :channel_id, @channels, :id, :channelname, 
      { 
        prompt: t('channel.add.prompt'),
        selected: params[:channel_id]
      }, 
      class: 'form-control', required: true %>
```

Another option - which I would prefer - is to set this value when you initialize the object for the form. This depends on how your `form_for` looks like, but it might look like this:

```
# in the controller
@model = Model.new(channel_id: params[:channel_id])

# in the view
<%= form_for @model do |f| %>
```

If it is done this way, then there is no need to change the `collection_select` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `selected:` key

```
<%= f.collection_select :channel_id, @channels, :id, :channelname, {prompt: (t "channel.add.prompt"), selected: "<id of record to be selected>"}, class: "form-control", :required => :true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<%= f.collection_select :channel_id, @channels, :id, :channelname, prompt: (t "channel.add.prompt"), class: "form-control", :required => :true, selected: params[:channel_id] || 2 %>
```

Comment: you can try `selected: params[:channel_id] || 2 ` update my post it will take channel id if it is not nil or default any value like  2